# copy inner html of a div and paste it in an other div with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this element:

```
<div id="divOne">
<button class="close-menu">close</button>
<ul>
    <li>hello</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I want to copy inner html of #divOne and paste it to other div when page is loading.

I do with this code but my button does not work anymore.

```
document.getElementById('divTwo').innerHTML = document.getElementById("divOne").innerHTML;
```

Thank you

Comment: where is the handler for button??

Comment: isn't that should be other way round?

Comment: use  document.getElementById('divTow').innerHTML = document.getElementById("divOne").innerHTML;

Comment: @MilindAnantwar this:  /* hide active menu if close menu button is clicked */
 [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".close-menu")).forEach(function(el,i) {
     el.addEventListener("click", function() {
         classie.remove(body, activeNav);
         activeNav = "";
         document.body.removeChild(mask);
     });
 });

Comment: Beware that by using .innerHTML if something changes in#divOne it will also change the #divTwo

Comment: @cssGEEK Can you elaborate your comment? `innerHTML` is just a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who still see this post:

If you want the buttons (onClick event,...) work after adding new HTML to an element, use the code below:

```
element.insertAdjacentHTML(position, text);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

Answer (score 3):

You need to [delegate](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) the click handler, something like

```js
// handle clicks on all document buttons
$(document).on('click', 'button', buttonClick);
// copy #divOne html to #divTwo
$('#divTwo').html($('#divOne').html());
               
// click handler demo
function buttonClick(e) {
  var result = $('#result');
  var id     = $(this.parentNode).attr('id');
  result.html('clicked button within: #' + id);
  // comment @cssGeek demo
  $('div').css('color', '#000');
  $('#'+id).css('color', 'red');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div id="divOne">
    <button class="close-menu">close</button>
    <ul>
      <li>hello</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="divTwo"></div>

  <div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Beware that by using .html() if something changes in#divOne it will also change the #divTwo

Comment: @cssGeek: sorry, but that's nonsense. See adjusted scripting in the example.

Answer (score 1):

*my button does not work anymore.*

Well in this case you have to delegate the event to the closest static parent or to the `document`:

I guess you are using jquery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.close-menu', function(e){
    console.log('clicked.');
});
```

*I want to copy inner html of #divOne and paste it to other div when page is loading.*

What you have posted is doing it other way round instead you have to do this:

```
document.getElementById('divTow').innerHTML = document.getElementById("divOne").innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
document.getElementById('divTwo').innerHTML = document.getElementById("divOne").innerHTML;
```

```html
<div id="divOne">
<button class="close-menu">close</button>
<ul>
    <li>hello</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="divTwo"></div>
```

Comment: May be u mean, divTwo, not a divTow?